# Django compatibility for Python 3.4 on windows

Tags: python, django

Is Django is fully supported for python version 3.4 on windows? I have another application developed on PySide framework which is not supported on Python 3.6.  Pyside is supported only up to python 3.4.

My intention is to retain Python 3.4 on my windows machine and use it for both PySide and Django. Is this better approach for both desktop and web application development?

Comment: If your question was adequately answered you can mark this question as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Django version 2.0 and earlier suppport python 3.4

Django version 2.1 and forward will not support python 3.4

From: [What python version can I use with Django?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django)